# Output negative values in a bar chart using stars to represent a range of three values

Tags: c++

This is the assignment.

1. Design and write a C++ program that inputs a series of 24 hourly temperatures from a file, and outputs a bar chart (using stars) of the temperatures for the day. (Hint; that is an Input file and the output of the program goes to the screen)
2. The temperature should be printed to the left of the corresponding bar, and there should be a heading that gives the scale of the chart.
3. The range of temperatures should be from -30 to 120 F . Because it is hard to display 150 characters on the screen, you should have each star represent a range of 3 degrees. That way, the bars will be at most 50 characters wide.

This is what I have.

```
//Include statements
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Variable declarations
int count;
float temperature;
float stars;

//Declare and open input file
ifstream inData;
inData.open("temperatures.txt");

//Program logic
cout << "Temperatures for 24 hours:" << endl;
cout <<setw(6) << "-30" << setw(9) << '0' << setw(10) << "30" << setw(10) << "60" << setw(10) << "90" << setw(10) << "120"<< endl;
while (inData >> temperature) {
    cout << setw(3) << temperature;
    if (temperature < 0) {
        count = 0;
        stars = round(temperature / 3)*-1;
        while (count <= stars) {
            cout << std::right<< setw(11)<< '*';
            count++;
        }
        cout << '|';
    }
    if (temperature > 0) {
        count = 0;
        stars = ceil(temperature / 3);
        cout << setw(12) << '|';
        while (count < stars) {
            cout << '*';
            count++;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << setw(12) << '|';
    }
    count++;
    cout << endl;
}
//Closing program statements
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Everything works except for when it reads negative values from the file. How do I line up the bar and output the stars from the bar to the left?

Here is an example of what the bar chart should look like [**this**](https://books.google.com/books?id=mxZBPSjSEYUC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=1.%09Design%20and%20write%20a%20C%2B%2B%20program%20that%20inputs%20a%20series%20of%2024%20hourly&ots=IDsOvmGJue&sig=0yet2EgArAxkoFXUmrLwBOssIzU&hl=en&ei=R8akTP-8MMWblgeP_7y4DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=1.%09Design%20and%20write%20a%20C%2B%2B%20program%20that%20inputs%20a%20series%20of%2024%20hourly&f=false)

Comment: *Everything works except for when it reads negative values from the file* -- Weren't you given these requirements before you wrote any code?  If so, shouldn't have this been part of your original design?  By jumping in and coding things before thinking them out is going to paint you into a box when you may realize you have to redo the entire program to fit the requirements.

Comment: I was given these requirements, that is correct. I am still new at this and am learning how to effectively tackle problems like this. I will take your advice and apply it to my problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with statement `cout << std::right<< setw(11)<< '*'`, which writes several stars, always filled with blanks in between. You seem to have misinterpreted `std::right` in a way as if it would "redirect" output direction from right to left henceforth. Yet it just modifies the default positioning of the fill characters, but output is still written from left to right.

As your scale is always from -30 to +120, I'd rather run a loop through this scale and check if the current position is in the respective temperature range. This is - in my opinion - easier to read than the `std::right`-things. It could look as follows.

```
int temperature;
cout << "Temperatures for 24 hours:" << endl;
cout <<setw(6) << "-30" << setw(9) << '0' << setw(10) << "30" << setw(10) << "60" << setw(10) << "90" << setw(10) << "120"<< endl;
while (inData >> temperature) {
    cout << setw(3) << temperature;
    int tempDiv3 = temperature / 3;
    for (int i=-30/3; i<=120/3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cout << '|';
        }
        else if (tempDiv3 < 0 && i >= tempDiv3 && i < 0) {
            cout << '*';
        }
        else if (tempDiv3 > 0 && i <= tempDiv3 && i > 0) {
            cout << '*';
        }
        else  {
            cout << ' ';
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I did not even think to use a for loop in this way.